# Discuss a particular question - Chat FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

From [FAQ of Web Application Chat](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If you want to discuss a certain question that has been posted on Web Applications, you can create a room for it.
> To do so, just prepend "chat." to the question link. For example, if you want to chat about https://serverfault.com/questions/145777, visit http://chat.serverfault.com/questions/145777. If there is an existing room for this question, you will enter it immediately. Otherwise, a new room will be created with you as the owner.

I found two issues on this topic:

1. Why https://serverfault.com/ is mentioned here, not https://webapps.stackexchange.com/?
2. Why prepending "chat." is not working for questions in the [meta site](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

1: that is just a bug; well fix the FAQ to pick up the correct parent site

2: we only have the one DNS entry; however (undocumented) "/questions/meta/145777" will do what you want

We still need to guage how key this is in terms of whether the we add complexity to the *core* Q&A UI that is only used in low% of questions.